# Get int from REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to get the number in a string using REGEX but it seem's not working..

My string : `<p>My awesome calendar</p> [calendar last="4"] !`

Regex : `/\[calendar last="[1-9]"]/g`

Result : `[calendar last="[1-9]"]`

I'd like to get the number of last events... should be : `4`

Comment: Use `/(\d+)/` to extract numbers, if your format is exactly as you've shown above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a capture group, which you use parentheses

```
/\[calendar last="([1-9])"]/g
```

You can then access that capture group's result by using `exec`

```js
var str = '<p>My awesome calendar</p> [calendar last="4"] !'
var regex = /\[calendar last="([1-9])"\]/g
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]) // 0 is the entire match, 1 is the first group
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `()` notation for the place you need and then use `replace` to get the value:

```
'<p>My awesome calendar</p> [calendar last="4"] !'.replace(/.*\[calendar last="([1-9])"\].*/g, '$1');
```